# Angular ui-Grid Splice doesn't work with array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid that I am trying to use to process bulk actions.  Items should be removed from the grid once the action is completed.  The problem is that the splice only works for every other record.  The rest of the code works as expected, but not the splice.  Every other record remains on the grid until I F5 to refresh the page (the backend functions actually delete the rows from the database - I was using splice to get a quicker view of the correct data without having to refresh the grid data once the database procedures complete).

Here is my controller code:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'dteDateReleaseRequestedByCompany', displayName: 'Requested Date'
            },

      {
          field: 'vchCompanyName', displayName: 'Company Name',
          cellTemplate: '<div style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;text-align:left;cursor:pointer" ng-click="grid.appScope.rowClick(row)">{{COL_FIELD}}</div>'
      },
      {
          field: 'CompanyID', width: 110, displayName: 'Company ID', visible:false
      },
      { field: 'vchOprCity', displayName: 'City' },
      { field: 'vchOprStateVchID', displayName: 'State' },
      {
          field: 'dteExpiresWithGracePeriod', displayName: 'Subscription', headerCellClass: 'center',
          cellTemplate: '<div style="text-align:center"><span ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field] | getSubscription | trustedhtml"></span></div>'
      },
      {
          field: 'Action', displayName: 'Release Action', 
          cellTemplate: '<div class="btn-group" ng-init="row.entity.Action=0"><input ng-model="row.entity.Action" type="radio" value="0" style="width:20px">&nbsp;None&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input ng-model="row.entity.Action" type="radio" value="1" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Accept&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input ng-model="row.entity.Action" type="radio" value="2" style="width:20px">&nbsp;Decline</div>'

      },

        ],
        showGridFooter: false,
        //enableFiltering: true,
        enableSorting: false,
        paginationPageSizes: [20, 40, 60],
        paginationPageSize: 20,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        exporterCsvFilename: 'PendingReleases.csv',
        exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 9 },
        exporterPdfTableStyle: { margin: [10, 10, 10, 10] },
        exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: { fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red' },
        exporterPdfHeader: { text: "Pending Release Requests", style: 'headerStyle' },
        exporterPdfFooter: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
            return { text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount.toString(), style: 'footerStyle' };
        },
        exporterPdfCustomFormatter: function (docDefinition) {
            docDefinition.styles.headerStyle = { fontSize: 22, bold: true, alignment: 'center' };
            docDefinition.styles.footerStyle = { fontSize: 10, bold: true, alignment: 'center' };
            return docDefinition;
        },
        exporterPdfOrientation: 'landscape',
        exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
        exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,
        exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

        }
    };

  $scope.process = function () {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.gridOptions.data.length; i++)
        {
            var id = $scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[i].entity.CompanyID;
            var action = $scope.gridApi.grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache[i].entity.Action;
            var index = i;

            if(action ==1)
            {
                $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);

                accept(id, index);
            }
            if(action == 2)
            {
                $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);

                decline(id, index);

            }

        }


    };

    function accept(id, index) {
        contractorService.acceptRelease(id);

    };
    function decline(id, index) {
        contractorService.declineRelease(id);

    };
```

Here is my HTML:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ManagePendingReleases";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
<script src="~/Scripts/app/Contractor/ContractorCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/Contractor/contractorService.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-grid-header-cell {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: black;
  background-color: #cfe7f1;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cfe7f1;
  display: table-cell;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 0;
}
</style>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="ContractorCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading" >Manage Pending Releases</div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ng-style="{height: (gridOptions.data.length*30)+32+'px'}" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process()">Process Actions</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is what my grid looks like:

[image]

When the Process Actions button is clicked, it is supposed to iterate through the rows and find which Action should happen on each record in the database.
When I step through the code it looks like the splice works for each record, but every other one remains on the grid.  Can anyone tell why I am getting this behavior?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Need all the relevant code to understand whats going on, plz add it.

Comment: Try this $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);

Comment: @EmirMarques `splice` changes the original array so doesnt matter.

Comment: @vinayakj right, but angular can generate this problem

Comment: @EmirMarques `splice` is pure javascript API, how come angular's object be any different than javascript object.

Comment: @EmirMarques - thanks for the suggestion but that made the grid equal to only what is being spliced.  The nearly whole grid disappeared until I hit F5 then all but what was removed came back.  I just don't understand why the splice would work for just every other record.

Comment: @vinahakj - what other relevant code do you need?  The HTML?  My MVC controller code won't tell you much as it uses a method to via the web api client to execute a stored procedure in the SQL database.

Comment: yes, all frontend related code, backend code is not needed, moreover a small jsFiddle, if you could

Comment: @vinayakj Some sugestion? I try this

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Are you sure you are entering inside the if ?

Comment: just a hunch but can you try `$scope.$apply()` after `splice` statement, not recommended though unless `ui-grid` had handled it already.

Comment: Tried $scope.$apply(), but every other one still does not splice from the grid.

Comment: @vinayakj - I removed my functions "accept() and decline()" just to see if the round trip to the MVC controller and the web api were causing some sort of "timing" issue so all I left was the splice for each iteration and still it only splices every other one.  This is crazy!  I'm working on plunker now to try to reproduce.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I kinda got the problem now, you are using the `length of array` in `for` loop on which you are doing `splice` also you are using `index` to remove item, but `splice` is reducing the array, so `index` also needs to change, so overcome this clone the data object do the splice operation and then assign cloned object to data

Comment: OOOH, I understand the problem now, thank you!  I just have to figure out how to clone the data.  Would Angular.copy do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `length` of array in `for` loop on which you are doing `splice` which in turn is reducing also you are using `index` to remove item, but `splice` is reducing the array, so `index` also needs to change.

So the closest plausible answer is, use `delete` instead of splice as `delete` doesn't change the `index`.

```
delete $scope.gridOptions.data[index]
```

Instead of

```
$scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Look this example. Notice how is excluded. The object of the index is obtained through a indexOf

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

  $scope.deleteRow = function(row) {
    var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
    $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.gridOptions = {};

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [{
    name: 'firstName'
  }, {
    name: 'lastName'
  }, {
    name: 'Delete',
    cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteRow(row)">Delete</button>'
  }];

  $scope.gridOptions.data = [{
    "firstName": "Cox",
    "lastName": "Carney",
    "company": "Enormo",
    "employed": true
  }, {
    "firstName": "Lorraine",
    "lastName": "Wise",
    "company": "Comveyer",
    "employed": false
  }, {
    "firstName": "Nancy",
    "lastName": "Waters",
    "company": "Fuelton",
    "employed": false
  }];

}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but that example is passing in a row object on a click event on a particular row.  I'm not passing in a row object because I am processing all rows at once.